# Can't use google play services on unity java plugin

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I have a plugin for Unity that is written in Java. In this plugin I need to get the new Google [Advertisement ID](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.co.il/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html) to do it, I have to add to the Manifest file:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

When I compile, Unity is throwing error:

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
/Applications/adt/sdk/build-tools/android-4.2.2/aapt package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -  J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "/Applications/adt/sdk/platforms/android-  19/android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

stderr[
AndroidManifest.xml:21: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
]
```

I also tried to add the Google play services jar to the [lugins/Androif folder but that didn't help.
What is the correct way to make it work?

Answer (score 25):

To fix this error, you have to copy the `version.xml` file from `android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/res/values/` into `Assets/Plugins/Android/res/values/` your Unity project's folder.

Comment: I tried just copying the version.xml and tried copying the entire res folder. No luck. What am I missing?

Comment: @AlmogC I'm not sure what you could have done wrong. Maybe try it in a brand new Unity project?

Comment: why isnt in Google setup instructions

Answer (score 2):

Don't copy all project into your Plugins/Android.

1. Config file Manifest.xml to right information. Copy to Plugins/Android.

   > ```
   >  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
   >               android:value="\ android app id " /> 
   >           <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
   >                   android:value="\ android app id " /> 
   >           <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
   >               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 
   >           <activity android:name="com.google.example.games.pluginsupport.SignInHelperActivity"
   >  />
   > ```
2. Copy  Google play services jar -> to Plugins/Android
3. Copy all res folder ->  to  Plugins/Android/res

Comment: Can you explain if I need to set the "\ android app id " to something or leave as is?

Comment: I tried the above and it didn't work. I copied the snippet as-is to the Application node in the Manifest.xml. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Android App ID is a string you can get from Google Developer Console. Go to here https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling -> Set up your game -> Create Client IDs

Answer (score 1):

An updated simple solution:

Today, i have same issue. 
I noticed that, when i copy `folder` from `android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/` named `google-play-services_lib` ; there is already this folder in `Assets/Plugins/Android` on unity.
And name of the copied folder is to be `goole-play-services_lib 1`.

So i only deleted this folder, and it is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

You need recent Google Play Services library project linked to your project, so during build time all resources from the project will also be available. You definitely got older library because `google_play_services_version` was just introduced recently. And you cannot just add `jar` to your project - it will not work. Just add Google Play Services as eternal library as documented.

Comment: i have api level 19, the newest. also, i use this plugin in a simple android java applications and it works, in there, i link the lib from the google play services api, but how do i link it in unity?