# Unity Android not Building with Google Play Plug-In

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine, google-play

I know many people have had issues with this when building for android and using the Google play Unity plug in.

Here is the error...
[image]

There are many threads about this issue and I have spent hours trying to solve it following them. But none of them worked for me. These are some of the things I tried...

[Can't use google play services on unity java plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728725/cant-use-google-play-services-on-unity-java-plugin)
[Android - Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348615/android-error-building-player-commandinvokationfailure-failed-to-re-package)
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/849592/error-building-player-commandinvokationfailure-fai-5.html
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/675074/android-error-building-player-commandinvokationfai.html

Most of them talk about moving the google_play_service_lib folder from the androidsdk\extra\google folder to plugins\android in Unity to make it work. I have tried this many times but it doesn't work.

To cover some of the basics. I am using Unity 5 and on Mac OS X Yosemite. My java SDK and Android SDK's are up to date as you can see here...

[image: picture of all the sdks that I have]

Also setting up the Unity Google Play Plugin for android also worked and I already have it building for iOS.

I do get this strange error in my Android SDK but I don't think that is the issue here...
[image: Image showing an error]

does my plugins file in Unity look right?
[image: Image of my plug-ins within Unity]

Thanks for the help!